# Common stock and ADR traded on the same exchange for one company? What's the difference between them?

Tags: investing, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, adr, common-stocks

I'm looking at Renesas Electronics Crop stock and they have two tickers, both traded on the OTC exchange but one of them is noted as ["common stock" (RNECF)](https://digital.fidelity.com/prgw/digital/research/quote/dashboard/summary?symbol=RNECF) and one is [noted as an ADR (RNECY)](https://digital.fidelity.com/prgw/digital/research/quote/dashboard/summary?symbol=RNECY).

I just learned that an ADR is a certificate that represents shares of a foreign company but how is that different than the RNECF which is listed as common stock and why is there 2 different listings? Is it better to invest in the common stock or the ADR? Is there less or more risk involved with either one? I'm still learning about investing as a whole so if you think I'm missing or could benefit from understanding a more fundamental concept please let me know as well.

Comment: If you're still learning about investing, maybe ADRs and the OTC market are not for you just yet? Just sayin...

Comment: @littleadv Perhaps not, but that's exactly why I'm here asking. Thanks, that thread does help!

Comment: FYI there is no "OTC" exchange - OTC's by definition trade  _outside_ an exchange. Some brokers and websites can help buy OTC securities but they carry some additional risks that listed securities do not have.